# How do I convert a whole column that is a string to date inside phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql

I exported a database from access to excel, saved it as a csv than imported to phpmyadmin. When I try to convert a column that is on the string formate to date, it always returns null, i don't know whats the problem.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?  Can you include sample input data, and then point out what the output should be?

Comment: COL1                                
2016-11-15 string                  
2016-11-16 string
2016-11-18 string
2016-11-21 string
2016-11-22 string

Comment: COL1
2016-11-15 date
2016-11-16 date
2016-11-18 date
2016-11-21 date
2016-11-22 date

Comment: i am using mysql btw

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear the data format of col1 in your table, if it is a string with format 'yyyy-mm-dd' (one date per row) you can use `STR_TO_DATE` function to convert that string to date in MySQL.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(col1, '%Y-%m-%d')
FROM `DUAL`;
```

Comment: sorry for the mess, the data is a string with the format 'yyyy-mm-dd', i want to change it to the date format.

Comment: Ok @RuanRoussenqAlves, try my query (it return col1 values convert to date). If you want to save dates in your table you will need to create a date column on it first.

Comment: i tryed your query, but it returns null

Comment: You can check it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37228404e2e392c89fcb2a8bf6f5c1c2)!

Comment: If the input string is illegal, the `STR_TO_DATE()` function returns NULL.

Comment: i exported a database from access to excel, saved it as a csv than imported to phpmyadmin. the format seems ok, but it always returns null.

Comment: Could you share in your question some INSERT statements from your database to try it?

Comment: Could you execute this query `SELECT col1, STR_TO_DATE(col1, '%Y-%m-%d') AS col1_date FROM \`DUAL\` WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL AND trim(col1) != '' LIMIT 10;` and copy and paste its output (without modifications)?